# What caused this motor to short?

Tags: hvac, electric-motor

These pics are from my ECM motor in my air handler.  I knew the motor was my problem when it failed a phase-resistance test between the windings.  The new motor passed the test and works great.  I opened up the old one and found some burnt residue, but that was it.  I cleaned it up and it passes the test now.  Any idea how this could have happened?  The wire is not melted or cut anywhere.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Something fell (or crawled) in there, perhaps burning up as it shorted the motor?

Comment: Carbon based life form becomes carbon based jumper.